# PHP cURL request headers isn't working with a global variable

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, gravity-forms-plugin

I've set a global variable to equal an access token, and when I print_($session_id) the token is visible. What I'd like to do is pass that variable into my CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, and have it equal to "Session" in the function get_field_data_id() below:

```
function get_session_id() {
global $session_id;

$curl = curl_init();
$session_url = "/auth";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $session_url ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "username: USER",
        "password: PASS",
        "authorizationkey: KEY"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$session_id = $response;

} add_filter( 'gform_after_submission_4', 'get_session_id' );

function get_field_data_id() {
global $session_id;

$curl = curl_init();
$file_url = "URL";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $file_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Session: {$session_id}"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;}
```

However when I run this function, I get an error message that the session ID is invalid. What am I missing?

```
{"Message":"Invalid Authorization. Session ID is invalid. "}
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm using the BytePro API, here is a link to the docs:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N14Orb61lh3zE9rAenyfBnn0g0XzrC0R/view?usp=sharing). I'm using the gravity forms hook gform_after_submission, `add_action( 'gform_after_submission_4', 'get_field_data_id', 10, 2 );` so it calls this function after a submission. I'm setting the $session_id in another cURL which I'll add above.

Comment: Basic debugging. Step 1, are you getting an expected value when you assign `$session_id`?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, `$session_id` is returning the proper value.

Comment: Enable curl debugging and look at the second request then. Do the headers and the message body look as expected? If so, the balance of probabilities suggests that your session ID is actually invalid.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I've tested both calls in postman. The first call does get the correct token, and the second call returns the desired response. If I print `global $session_id;` in the second function, it does return the token.

Comment: You need to debug your code's request, not postman's